# поиск нейросети

Tags: нейронные-сети

Нужно создать программу, которая определяла бы насколько человек на фотографии похож на заданную группу людей(50 фотографий). Т.е. насколько я понимаю нужно нейросеть настроить на эти 50 фотографий, и потом, нейросеть сможет определить, насколько данная фотография похожа на эти 50.
 Вопрос. Есть ли готовая нейросеть, ориентированная на лица с фотографий, что бы такое реализовать?

Answer (score 2):

```
> Нужно создать программу, которая определяла бы насколько человек 
  на фотографии похож на заданную группу людей
> Есть ли готовая нейросеть, ориентированная на лица с фотографий, 
  что бы такое реализовать?
```

обучить нейросеть - это долго и сложно. 
например, для разработки системы Google для конкурса по распознаванию лиц Megaface, наподобилось около 1000 серверов. см. [тут](http://www.vedomosti.ru/technology/articles/2015/12/07/619875-rossiiskii-startap-google)

вместо нейросети можно использовать SURF.

на nuget.org скачайте пакет OpenCvSharp-AnyCPU.

к своему проекту подключите сборки OpenCvSharp.dll и OpenCvSharp.CPlusPlus.dll

 
для поиска и вывода ключевых точек изображения пишете примерно так:

```
var src = new Mat(@"C:\Images\test.jpg", LoadMode.GrayScale);
var s = new OpenCvSharp.CPlusPlus.SURF(300.);
var d = s.Detect(src);
var m = new Mat()
Cv2.DrawKeypoints(src, d, m);
Window.ShowImages(m);
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам скорее всего сюда http://opencv.org/
С определениями похоже перегнули

Comment: Нормальный ответ, но хотелось бы чуть больше подробностей - а то заминусуют и удалят как ссылку :(

Answer (score 0):

Задачи распознавания изображений решаются **глубокими нейросетями** или сверточными. Обычными нейросетями такие задачи не решить.